# Surjective proper cover by ordinary varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, positive-characteristic

Let $X$ be smooth proper variety over a finite field $k$ of  positive characteristic $p$. Assume that $X$ is not ordinary, then my question is if there exists a smooth, projective ordinary $Y$ with a surjective proper morphism $Y\to X$. A (naive) approach would be to mimick what we do in the resolution of singularity by blowing up $X$ along a subvariety. However, for instance by Prop 4.2.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110070.pdf), the blow-up along $Z\subset X$ is ordinary if and only if both $X,Z$ are. I had a hope that I could maybe understand the situation better for the case of abelian varieties, but must admit to being stuck. I'd appreciate any input, I'm not quite sure what to believe.

Comment: this is definitely false in the category of abelian varieties. The isogeny category of abelian varieties is semisimple and so if you had a surjection $A \to E$ from an abelian variety to a supersingular elliptic curve, then $A$ would be isogenous to a variety with $E$ as a direct factor and in particular would not be ordinary. 

(This isn't an answer, though, since you don't require $Y$ to be an abelian variety.)

Comment: @hunter its not an answer, but it is interesting and I do appreciate it since I hadn't thought of it :)